# Excel VBA: replace top line of textbox from cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox in excel with a paragraph style entry. I want to automate adding a line from cell A1 to replace the top line of that paragraph.

Basically there's a title line and then a paragraph in the textbox, and I want to be able to replace the title line with the value of cell A1 through VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Use Split to get an array of the lines, then edit the first line, then Join the lines back together. E.g.

```
strArray = Split(yourStringWithNewLines, vbNewLine)
strArray(0) = "New First Line"
yourStringWithNewLines = Join(strArray, vbNewLine)
```